# Commenting a Report

Tags: jasper-reports, birt

Imagine an HTML based report which shows some data (for example) of process runs.

It is very likely that the data will contain some exceptions for example very long runs or other KPIs which are out of bounds.

Is there some kind of framework or tool out there with which I can simply click on such an execption, write a comment (why this was exceptional and how it got solved) and the data will be marked as "exception, but handled"?

I just hoped that BIRT or JasperReports would have something like that out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be a good feature in JasperReports Server, but it's not there today. You could consider this one specific case of the more general requirement to have some collaboration features. It would be good if you would log it; that would raise its priority.

Comment: thanx for your reply. At least I now know that I have to look for it in JasperReports. But since I haven't worked with jasper yet, I also don't know how to log a feature request - so feel free to log it :-) or point me to a page where I can do it :-)

Comment: Good point. The appropriate place to log enhancement requests (and bugs) for the JasperReports Server is on the tracker here: http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperserver/tracker